# Problemas con la función sprintf en C

Tags: c, string, sprintf

Mi problema es el siguiente, debo escribir un código que reciba por teclado números mayores a cero y concatenarlos en una sola cadena de caracteres, pero al compilar me salta esto en consola:

> ```
> main.c:21:19: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sprintf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>    21 |       sprintf (num[i], "%d", c);
>       |                ~~~^~~
>       |                   |
>       |                   char
> ```

Mi código es este:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  int i, n, c;
  printf ("Dimension del vector: ");
  scanf ("%d", &n);
  char num[n];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      printf ("Ingrese un numero: ");
      scanf ("%d", &c);
      // leer sC3lo nC:meros que sean mayores que 0
      if (c < 1) {
      printf ("Ingrese un numero mayor que cero: ");
      scanf ("%d", &c);
      }
      // sprintf para cambiar de entero a caracter
      sprintf (num[i], "%d", c);
    }
  printf("%s", num);
}
```

La verdad no sé cuál sería el error y menos la solución, así que agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Es una advertencia. Puedes pasarla por alto pero es buena idea tratar de corregirlas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenes que pasar el array num por referencia:

```
sprintf (&num[i], "%d", c);
```

Comment: Eternamente agradecido. Saludos.

Comment: Técnicamente no sería una referencia. El operador & produce la dirección de una variable, un apuntador.